# Using pandas to add csv to azure sql with pymssql

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc, pymssql

Im trying to add a CSV file into Azure SQL with python.
I  was wondering if anyone could assist.
I am using a Mac M1 and have had issues getting pyodbc to work with my machine, so shifted to pymsql. Any help is appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import pymssql

df = pd.read_csv("/Users/username/Documents/PowerBi/scraper/Players and Salaries.csv")

server = 'sqlserver' 
database = 'dbtest' 
user = 'James' 
password = 'abES4grg3' 

conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, database)
c1 = conn.cursor()

#df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
     c1.execute('INSERT INTO Players_Salaries (personID,PlayerName,Salary) values(?,?,?)', row.personID, row.PlayerName, row.Salary)

conn.close()
```

CSV----

```
<bound method NDFrame.head of      personID             PlayerName        Salary
0           0           LeBron James  $44,474,988 
1           1           Kevin Durant  $44,119,845 
2           2            Paul George  $42,492,568 
3           3          Kawhi Leonard  $42,492,492 
4           4  Giannis Antetokounmpo  $42,492,492 
..        ...                    ...           ...
378       378       Brandon Williams     $502,080 
379       379           Xavier Sneed     $502,080 
380       380         Jordan Schakel     $502,080 
381       381            DJ Augustin     $333,333 
382       382      Ishmail Wainright   $1,701,305 

[383 rows x 3 columns]>
```

Output ---

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/jamesmarchetti/Documents/PowerBi/Server_Testing/Untitled-2.ipynb Cell 2' in <cell line: 14>()
     12 #df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)
     14 for index, row in df.iterrows():
---> 15      c1.execute('INSERT INTO Players_Salaries (personID,PlayerName,Salary) values(?,?,?)', row.personID, row.PlayerName, row.Salary)
     18 #c1.execute('SELECT * FROM Players_Salaries')
     19 #data = c1.fetchall()
     20 #print(data)
     22 conn.close()

File src/pymssql/_pymssql.pyx:452, in pymssql._pymssql.Cursor.execute()

TypeError: execute() takes at most 2 positional arguments (4 given)
```

Comment: Try passing the parameter values as a tuple: `(row.personID, row.PlayerName, row.Salary)`

Comment: Thanks this worked; I also needed %d and %s for values and .commit()